# How do I write a findMany that will get in chunks?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember 1.5.1
Ember-Data 1.0 beta 7

I've tried to modify the DS.ActiveModelAdapter's findMany so it'll get in chunks of 40... this is because I can't use the links feature and it seems to be generating 400 errors because it has too many ids in the URL its creating.

I tried using this adapter, but I keep getting error messages that look like this:

```
    Error: Assertion Failed: Error: no model was found for 'super'
```

Here's my Adapter:

```
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
        findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
          self = this;
          return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var idsPerRequest = 40;
            var totalIdsLength = ids.length;
            var numberOfBins = Math.ceil( totalIdsLength / idsPerRequest ); // number per bin
            var bins = [];
            ids.forEach( function(someId, index) {
              var thisBinIndex = index % numberOfBins;
              var thisBin = Ember.A( bins[thisBinIndex] );
              thisBin.pushObject(someId);
              bins[thisBinIndex] = thisBin;
            });

            var requestPromises = bins.map(function(binOfIds) {
              return self.ajax(self.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: { ids: binOfIds } });
            });

            Ember.RSVP.all(requestPromises).then(function(resolvedBinRequests) {
              var resolvedObjects = Em.A([]);
              resolvedBinRequests.forEach(function(resolvedBin) {
                resolvedObjects.addObjects(resolvedBin);
              });
              resolve(resolvedObjects);
            }, function(error) {
              reject(error);
            });
          });
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me out with this? It'd be really appreciated. Am I just missing something obvious or have I perhaps done something silly?

Thanks in advance!

[edit] Okay so further to this I've figured out why it's not working, and that's because the response that's coming back is a promise for the JSON payload, but what I'm doing is joining multiples of these into an array and returning that... which obviously won't be right... but what I need to do is merge the arrays inside the objects returned into one, I think (in concept)... I'm not really sure how to do this in actuality, though... I've tried various things, but none of them seem to work well... :(

Comment: Could you post what you expect the response to one of these request should look like? I suspect 
    ````Error: Assertion Failed: Error: no model was found for 'super'```` error is coming from the serializer after the `findMany` promise has successfully resolved.

Comment: Also you could just manually hook up the associated records without using the `hasMany` until the other issue is resolved, ugly, but it'd be obvious, and a clean enough band-aid.

Comment: @kingpin2k what do you mean by "manually hook up"? they *are* manually hooked up at the moment, which is the problem - findMany is calling huge requests with multiple ids (about 80 of them) and that means that the requests don't get sent through because they become invalid (400 error code in the JS console).

Comment: (assuming by "manually hooking up" you mean not loaded on the route, and it just loads when it needs it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally worked out how to make this work.

I'll share my answer here for future posterity ;-)

Of interest is that the required response had to be a promise and it had to contain a straight up JS object, so I "munged" all the responses into one JS object and manually built the pluralized camelized type key... I wasn't sure how else to do this. So... sorry it's so hacky, but this actually works and lets me fix my app for now until the "links" feature is working again.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
      self = this;
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var idsPerRequest = 40;
        var totalIdsLength = ids.length;
        var numberOfBins = Math.ceil( totalIdsLength / idsPerRequest ); // number per bin
        var bins = [];
        ids.forEach( function(someId, index) {
          var thisBinIndex = index % numberOfBins;
          var thisBin = Ember.A( bins[thisBinIndex] );
          thisBin.pushObject(someId);
          bins[thisBinIndex] = thisBin;
        });

        // build an array of promises, then resolve using Ember.RSVP.all
        var requestPromises = bins.map(function(binOfIds) {
          return self.ajax(self.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: { ids: binOfIds } });
        });

      // build the required return object, which is a promise containing a plain JS object
      // note this can't be an Ember object
        Ember.RSVP.all(requestPromises).then(function(resolvedBinRequests) {
        var pluralizedDecamelizedTypeKey = type.typeKey.decamelize().pluralize();
        var resolvedObjects = Em.A([]);
        var returnObject = {};
        returnObject[pluralizedDecamelizedTypeKey] = resolvedObjects;
          resolvedBinRequests.forEach(function(resolvedBin) {
          var theArray = resolvedBin[pluralizedDecamelizedTypeKey];
            resolvedObjects.addObjects(theArray);
          });
        var responsePromise = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(returnObject);
          resolve(responsePromise);
        }, function(error) {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much control you have over the back-end, but this seems like a perfect use case for using `links` instead of returning all of the ids.

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('bar', {async:true})
});


App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

Then when you query for `foo` your json returns a link instead of a list of ids

```
{
  foo: {
    id:1,
    links: {
      bars: '/foo/1/bars'  // or anything, you could put /bars?start=1&end=9000
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example with 1000 relationship records hitting a simple endpoint:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/579/edit

Comment: links doesn't work because of a bug in the current version of beta (7) where partial loads clear out the associations. (as far as I understand it this is the issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1790) As I understand it, this is supposed to fix that: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1791

Comment: But yeah, I did try links, and this would work for the most part... except that I think there's still a case where it tries to load a whole bunch of ids which are over the max URL request size and it errors again.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm torn on the partial load, honestly I think partial loads should blast away properties, they should represent what's currently on the server, but I could see an issue where maybe this shouldn't hold true on save(update).  To your second comment though, you define the url, so even if it's a billion ids it only matters if you attempt to include a url naming each id.

Comment: Well I don't want to do the partial reload. Ember data is doing it itself depending on what has been loaded and what hasn't (if I understand correctly). This issue https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/241 is where I got the original code from that I modified for my use case. Originally I'd thought it'd just work until I read the new ember data source for the adapter, then I just tried to fit it into that.

Comment: The default behaviour of findMany for both these adapters (RestAdapter and ActiveSerializerAdapter) is that it actually just tries to send a big-ass ids array over the params... this is the actual source code from the adapter source - just one line of code for findMany's body: return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: { ids: ids } });

Comment: yeah, when ids are provided that's the stock implementation, unlike links.  The boring way of manually hooking up (essentially setting a property on the record) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/583/edit .  I don't think this gets blasted away on partial update, but I could be wrong (guessing this since it's not an attribute)

Comment: Oh right... yeah I can't do that because my app loads a data-defined nth level deep hierarchy of objects. It's pretty much impossible to manually load everything because I don't know what to load in advance... unless you're suggesting I put the store find calls into the model itself? In which case... my brain will explode ;-)

Comment: In other words, I have items, which can be a parent for childItems, and also can have a referredItem... and those items can also have childItems... etc. (there are about 4 types of these associations).

Comment: Hah, I'm definitely not saying hook up and use the store in a model, that would be heresy.  Back to POJOs ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some feedback I updated this response to attempt to extract the response payloads in the serializer instead of attempting to mimic the store's logic in the adapter.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wegiy/60/edit

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
    // build an array of promises, then resolve using Ember.RSVP.all
    var idsPerRequest = 40;
    var totalIdsLength = ids.length;
    var numberOfBins = Math.ceil( totalIdsLength / idsPerRequest ); // number per bin
    var bins = [];
    ids.forEach( function(someId, index) {
      var thisBinIndex = index % numberOfBins;
      var thisBin = Ember.A( bins[thisBinIndex] );
      thisBin.pushObject(someId);
      bins[thisBinIndex] = thisBin;
    });

    var requestPromises = bins.map(function(binOfIds) {
      return self.ajax(self.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: { ids: binOfIds } });
    });

    return Ember.RSVP.all(requestPromises);
  }
});

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  extractFindMany: function(store, type, responsePayloads) {
    // responsePayloads is the resolved value from the Ember.RSVP.all(requestPromises) promise

    var serializer = this;
    var extractedResponses = responsePayloads.map(function(payload) {
      return serializer.extractArray(store, type, payload);
    });
    // extractedResponses is an array of arrays. We need to flatten it into 1 array.
    return [].concat.apply([], extractedResponses);
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of hacky? like... if the store's internal behaviour changes, I'd have to change that code, wouldn't I? can I just return an array and lazily populate it?

Comment: By the way, this isn't *my* original findMany, it's the adapter's... it looked like this:

//  findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
//    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: { ids: ids } });
//  },

Comment: Yeah. This is defiantly hacky and there is likely a better solution. A better one might involve creating a custom `extractFindMany` on the `ApplicationSerializer` that knows how to work with an array of responses.

Comment: Heya, could you please explain why you add return requestPromises[0]; to the end then call? That's the first ajax request call, right?

I tried your code and it doesn't work very well either... (records are missing). I thought it would be relatively easy to achieve this, but it seems slightly complicated.

Comment: Given that the "standard" findMany returns an ajax call (ie promise) which returns an array of data, I thought my original code would work, because it's a promise that returns an array of data... i even tried to use the ajax call so it'd be the same as the original... :( Maybe I don't understand what ajax returns (true!)

Comment: I'm not sure what your backend's response looks like but I had assumed the ajax call was getting an object that had a key for the record type you were requesting (e.g. `{comments: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}`). I have updated my example to be less hacky and take advantage of the `ApplicationSerializer`. I also put together a jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wegiy/60/edit where I added some mock response data of what I am assuming your backend might look like. (Although I could be entirely wrong with this assumption.)

Comment: erm... I'm using ActiveModelSerializer adapter... so of course I'm using the ActiveModelSerializer gem with Rails... sorry I thought that was obvious.